# Spring data causing MySQL max key length exceeded

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I have the following code segment (generated by Spring Data / Eclipselink)

```
    CREATE TABLE abnormal_flags (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL 
UNIQUE, created DATETIME NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, uuid 
LONGBLOB NOT NULL UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

With MySQL it results in the following:

```
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

This is the connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/mynewdb?
useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
&serverTimezone=UTC
```

I have seen and resolved this before, however in this case I am not able to see where the issue is?  Is it because the uuid has been converted to a longblob?  I can't see why this would be an issue as it is not a key?

I removed the unique constraint on uuid with the same result

Apologies if I am the victim of a brain fade!

Comment: use `varchar(191)` instead

Comment: for the uuid field?  Due to unicode?

Comment: no, for the code and description

Comment: so I think it results from a change in the default character set to utf8mb4? and the consequential requirement for more storage for unique constrained fields?  Maybe you you add that to an answer, I can allocate the credits - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767
>   bytes

The above exception is clear enough, you have hit the limit.

Change `varchar(255)` to something below to 255, eg `varchar(191)`